# Where is $SPARK_HOME on an EC2 instance?

Tags: pyspark, aws

I am working on an EC2 instance with anaconda and pyspark pre-installed. My $SPARK_HOME variable is not set. Any ideas on how to locate my spark home?

Comment: it's an env variable; it's set like this (export PATH=${PATH}:/home/user_name/bin)

Comment: I don't have a /home/ubuntu(user name)/bin directory. I'm asking for the actual location of my spark's home directory on my machine.